# transfering from host to locall host with all posts and

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, function, content-management-system

i am working on a WordPress site,i changed theme,but it dost word well, i need the site to be live all of the day with one of the themes ( because of information);
i want to change the new theme's settings locally,and after that change the theme to work well, and i need the site's information and posts and ....
i tried and searched more about this ,but i couldn't find something useful

how can i transfer the site to localhost with all posts to change the theme? is it possible or not?
or how can i work with a theme but i have another theme on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can do this easily

**If** you have a full access to your site and host (FTP, phpmyadmin etc).

### Fisrt:

Get backup of your DB(Database) from cpanel and then your whole wordpress site from ftp.

### Second:

In yourdb.sql file rename the links like:
Find only `yoursite.com/` and replace with `localhost/foldername/`

**Note:** Please do not click on replace all its a precaution but not neccessry

### Third:

Third and final import your db on `localhost/phpmyadmin` (First create DB then upload to it), then change your change your mysql credentials in `wp-config.php` Like:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'Your DB Name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

then create a folder in `xampp/htdocs/` and paste your whole wordpress site backup

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i did, but i couldnt fix the sql,and it made error,what is your mean about "change your change your mysql credentials in wp-config.php"?

Comment: i could copy and ...., but i have just theme and the majules and i dont have the posts and other informations,i think it is because of sql file,i changed once but it didnt work,could you explain again?

Comment: sorry to answer late, if you have no sql then you can never get the posts ..... "change your mysql credentials in wp-config.php" means Like SQL Host, SQL user, SQL password and DB name